# JAVA / SPRING JPA : Not returning dependence at creation

Tags: java, spring, database, rest, jpa

First, I apologize if my english is unclear ; I am french.
I also am a very junior developer, and this is my first real personal project with no tutorial or whatsoever.

I am having some trouble with my Rest api.
I use java 11 and Spring/JPA

I have two DO classes that each represent a table in the database : Artist and Country.
An artist can have several nationalities, and a country can have several artist born in it.
So that means : many to many.

I joined them with an Association table ; ArtistNationality, that is also a class.
I know I could do without an additional class but, since in my app some relations also have some extra-fields (like the year of an award) I decided that all many to many relationships would be materialized the same way, by "join"classes (sorry I really have an hard time to explain in english)

When I create an Artist, I want my response json to contain the created artist with all its nationalities. But it always comes null.

The creation works fine. But here is the response :
What is odd is the results of my API call.
Here is the result of POST method :

```
{
"artistFirstName": "OH",
"artistLastName": "Test",
"artistBiography": "Je suis un test.",
"artistBirthDate": "1380-11-10",
"artistDeathDate": "1500-11-12",
"artistNationalities": [],
"artist_ID": 3
```

}

As you can see, nationalities come null, always.
What is expected, is the same as when I do a find or findall :

```
   {
"artistFirstName": "OH",
"artistLastName": "Test",
"artistBiography": "Je suis un test.",
"artistBirthDate": "1380-11-10",
"artistDeathDate": "1500-11-12",
"artistNationalities": [
    {
        "nationality": {
            "countryId": 1,
            "countryName": "Andorre",
            "countryShortCode": "AD",
            "countryFlagFileName": "ad_16.png"
        },
        "nationalityId": 5
    },
    {
        "nationality": {
            "countryId": 12,
            "countryName": "Autriche",
            "countryShortCode": "AT",
            "countryFlagFileName": "at_16.png"
        },
        "nationalityId": 6
    }
],
"artist_ID": 3
}
```

What I don't understand is that my save method returns the result of a "find" method so why isn't it the same ?? Find and findall work perfectly, and the insertion also works fine.

Here are the DataObject classes, I shortened them to leave only the fields related to question but of course they all come with their constructors and getters/setter stuff :

**Artist class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "artist")
public class Artist implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id_artist")
private final Integer ARTIST_ID;

@OneToMany(targetEntity = ArtistNationality.class, mappedBy = "artistIdAsForeignKey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<ArtistNationality> artistNationalities;
```

**Artist DTO**

```
public class ArtistDto {
private final Integer ARTIST_ID;
private String artistFirstName;
private String artistLastName;
private String artistBiography;
private String artistBirthDate;
private String artistDeathDate;
private List<NationalityDto> artistNationalities;
```

**Country class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "id_country")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private final Integer COUNTRY_ID;   


@OneToMany(targetEntity = ArtistNationality.class, mappedBy = "countryIdAsForeignKey", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonBackReference
private List<ArtistNationality> artistsComingFromCountry;
```

** COUNTRY DTO **

```
public class CountryDto {

private int countryId;
private String countryName;
private String countryShortCode;
private String countryFlagFileName;
```

**ArtistNationality class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="artist_x_nationality")
public class ArtistNationality implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="id_nationality")
private final Integer NATIONALITY_ID;

@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
@JsonBackReference
@JoinColumn(name= "fk_nationality_to_artist")
private Artist artistIdAsForeignKey;

@ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JsonBackReference   
@JoinColumn(name="fk_nationality_to_country")
private Country countryIdAsForeignKey;
```

**Nationality Dto:**

```
public class NationalityDto {
private final Integer NATIONALITY_ID;
private CountryDto nationality;
```

**ArtistService :**

```
@Service
public class ArtistServiceImpl implements IArtistService {

@Autowired
private IArtistDao artistDao;
@Autowired
private IArtistDoDtoMapper mapper;
@Autowired
private IArtistValidator validator;
@Autowired 
private IArtistNationalityDao nationalityDao;


@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<ArtistDto> findAll() {
    List<ArtistDto> resultList = new ArrayList<ArtistDto>();
    List<Artist> artistsFromDatabase = artistDao.findAll();
    if (artistsFromDatabase != null && !artistsFromDatabase.isEmpty()) {            
        resultList = mapper.mapDoListToDto(artistsFromDatabase);
    }
    return resultList;
}

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ArtistDto find(final int id) {
    Optional<Artist> optArtistFromDatabase = artistDao.findById(id);
    if (!optArtistFromDatabase.isPresent()) {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
    Artist artistFromDatabase = optArtistFromDatabase.get();
    ArtistDto result = mapper.mapDoToDto(artistFromDatabase);
    return result;
}

@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ArtistDto save(final ArtistDto objDto) {
    
    if(validator.isValidForDatabase(objDto)){

        //Save without nationalities (mapper does not map it);
        Artist artistToSave = mapper.mapDtoToDo(objDto);  
        int artistId = artistDao.save(artistToSave).ARTIST_ID();

        //Add the id of the artist to all his nationalities, then save the nationalities
        for (NationalityDto nationality : objDto.getArtistNationalities()){
            ArtistNationality doNationality = new ArtistNationality(nationality.getNationalityId());
            doNationality.setArtistIdAsForeignKey(new Artist(artistId));     
            doNationality.setCountryIdAsForeignKey(new Country(nationality.getNationality().getCountryId()));
            nationalityDao.save(doNationality);
        }

        ArtistDto returnArtist = this.find(artistId);
        return returnArtist;
    }
    throw new InsertionException("Invalid object. Could not insert into database.");
}
```

**Mappers :**

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public ArtistDto mapDoToDto(final Artist pDataObject) {               
    ArtistDto artistDto = new ArtistDto(pDataObject.ARTIST_ID());
    if (artistValidator.isNotNullAndNotEmpty(pDataObject.getArtistFirstName())) {
        artistDto.setArtistFirstName(pDataObject.getArtistFirstName());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataObject.getArtistLastName())) {
        artistDto.setArtistLastName(pDataObject.getArtistLastName());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataObject.getArtistBiography())) {
        artistDto.setArtistBiography(pDataObject.getArtistBiography());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataObject.getArtistBirthDate())) {
        artistDto.setArtistBirthDate(pDataObject.getArtistBirthDate());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataObject.getArtistDeathDate())) {
        artistDto.setArtistDeathDate(pDataObject.getArtistDeathDate());
    }       

    List<NationalityDto> artistNationalities = new ArrayList<NationalityDto>();
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataObject.getArtistNationalities())) {
        System.out.println("yes, we're in !");           
        for (ArtistNationality nationality : pDataObject.getArtistNationalities()) {
            NationalityDto nDto = new NationalityDto(nationality.getNationalityId());
            CountryDto cDto = countryMapper.mapDoToDto(nationality.getCountryIdAsForeignKey());
            nDto.setNationality(cDto);                
            artistNationalities.add(nDto);
        }

    }
    artistDto.setArtistNationalities(artistNationalities);
    return artistDto;
}

/**
 * Note : we add nationality separately since we do not have Artist's ID yet.
 */
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public Artist mapDtoToDo(final ArtistDto pDataTransfertObject) {
    System.out.println(pDataTransfertObject.toString());
    Artist artist = new Artist(pDataTransfertObject.getARTIST_ID());
    if (artistValidator.isNotNullAndNotEmpty(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistFirstName())) {
        artist.setArtistFirstName(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistFirstName());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistLastName())) {
        artist.setArtistLastName(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistLastName());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistBiography())) {
        artist.setArtistBiography(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistBiography());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistBirthDate())) {
        artist.setArtistBirthDate(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistBirthDate());
    }
    if (artistValidator.isOptionPresent(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistDeathDate())) {
        artist.setArtistDeathDate(pDataTransfertObject.getArtistDeathDate());
    }
    return artist;
}
```

This is the Json I send to my controller :

```
{
"ARTIST_ID" : null,
"artistFirstName":"OH",
"artistLastName":"Test",
"artistBiography":"Je suis un test.",
"artistBirthDate":"1380-11-10",
"artistDeathDate": "1500-11-12",
"artistNationalities": [{       
        "nationality": {            
            "countryId" : 1         
    }
},      
        {"nationality":{
            "countryId": 12
        }
    }
                                                
                                                ]
```

}

I also had to find a trick to save nationalities after artist because when I sent nationalities to database, jpa did not automatically add the saved artist to the nationality and the nationality was saved only with the country data, as you can see in the save method and the dto to do mapper.

I am sorry if it is not really clear, I do my best in english, thank you for understanding.

Answer (score 1):

If your find and findAll is working then, you should be able to override return from save and use find jpa method using the artist id returned by save in your service layer that way you will have a complete json to return.

Comment: this is already what I do as you can see in my service save method, but it does not work :( I even tried to call save from controller then find also from controller because I thought it could be due to transactional annotations in service méthods but I always get the same result :(

Comment: that is strange if the data persist and your other calls return a complete object. are you sure the data you pass to the api call persists? otherwise try using saveAndFlush if you are just using save method. Cause save does not persist until it has to but saveAndFlush immediately flushes all the changes to database.

Comment: I added the saveAndFlush but it does not change anything. I guess it persists since I get data in my Artist artist = dao.save(artistToSave) and my API sends back the "shortened" result when I only do a create. The only alternative I have is to manually add the nationalities to the dto artist once I persisted them and got their ID. This works. Maybe it comes from the @transactional ? I don't know how this really works. But yeah, very strange. A former teacher of mine helped me looking for the issue but didnt find it either. It's not a big deal since I've a workaround but that really puzzles me.

Comment: Also, when I perform a "select" on my db table I got the data and everything is fine :/ thank you for helping me.